# VBA simple parse

Tags: html, vba, parsing, internet-explorer, dom

I am using vba ( & internetexplorer object) to convert CSUIP to ISIN (these are financial security unique identification codes) from the following website http://www.isincodes.net/convert-cusip-to-isin.php.

I have so far created a vba code (in following order) that:
1. manipulates the US/CA dropdown box
2. inputs my CUSIP into the inputbox
3. clicks the "Covert"Button

```
Sub cusip_is2()

'declare variables
Set objie = CreateObject("internetExplorer.Application")

objie.Visible = True

'go to website
objie.navigate ("http://www.isincodes.net/convert-cusip-to-isin.php")
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until objie.readyState = 4

'input the CA in the country ID step1
objie.document.getelementbyID("country").Value = "CA"

'input 912796HQ5 in text box as desired CUSIP to convert
objie.document.getelementbyID("appendedInputButton").Value = "912796HQ5"


'press the button to convert
Set ElementCol = objie.document.getElementsByTagName("button")
 For Each btnInput In ElementCol
    btnInput.Click
 Next btnInput

'wait until the pages loads (not sure if I need this)
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until objie.readyState = 4

'added extra few seconds incase HMTL document is updating
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

'created userform to look at the data to see if I can find the converted CUSIP - WHICH I CANNOT (HELPPPPP!!!!)
Userfrom_Web_Code.Textbox_Webform.Text = objie.body.innerText
Userfrom_Web_Code.Show


'clean up and try again for the next failure LOL
objie.Quit
Set objie = Nothing
End Sub
```

From my research I know that I keep getting the source code but I want the DOM, this is where I am having trouble. Please see EXTRACT of source code on the website once I have inputted "CA" for country and the CUSIP "912796HQ5", and note that the id tag with results contains nothing.

```html
 <p>Enter a CUSIP and a correct ISIN will be calculated for you, if possible:</p>
                    <form class="form-inline">
                        <div class="input-append">
                            <select id="country" style="width:60px;">
                                <option value="CA">CA</option>
                                <option value="US" selected>US</option>
                            </select>
                            <input type="text" maxlength="9" class="span3" id="appendedInputButton">
                            <button type="button" class="btn">Convert</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                    <div id="results"></div>

                    <br><br>
                                    </div>

                <div class="span4">
                    <h4>What is a CUSIP?</h4>
                    <p>A CUSIP is a 9-character alphanumeric code which identifies a North American financial security.</p>
                    <p>
                        A CUSIP consists of three parts:<br>
                        &#8226; A six-character issuer code<br>
                        &#8226; A two-character issue number<br>
                        &#8226; A single check digit.<br><br>
                        For example: 780259206 (Royal Dutch Shell-A)
                    </p>
```

conversely when I check the inspect element which takes me to the "DOM" then I can see this under id results.

```html
<div id="results" style="display: block;"><br>
<b>Strict Standards</b>:  Non-static method Validate_CUSIP::validate() should not be called statically in <b>/home/isincode/public_html/action/c.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br>
<p class="text-success"><strong>Correct ISIN: CA912796HQ58</strong></p></div>
```

Can anyone please help me solve this problem in vba.

Note that I know that you can create an algorithm yourself in vba/excel to do the conversion of CUSIP to ISIN however I want to do this project in VBA to learn parsing. I am also very new to coding and have had limited exposure to please be kind and explain everything you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Please see if the following edit will suit you:

```
....
....
'added extra few seconds incase HMTL document is updated
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)

Dim ISIN As String
ISIN = Right(objie.document.getelementbyID("results").innerText,12) 'the 12 rightmost characters
Debug.Print "ISIN you are looking for is: " & ISIN
....
```

Edit the code to do something usefull with the ISIN-string

Comment: Hey Carmelid, seems to be working on my home computer, will try and on my work one which is the one I had trouble with. Can't believe it was just one second off LOL. Massive thanks for your time is also in order.